# Set default label and value to Select component MUI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want the select component to have a default label of Every 7 days and a default value of '7' but as soon as the page gets rendered the value changes to 2 and there is no label at all in the select box.

```
const CLEAN_UP_DASHBOARD = [
    { value: '2', label: 'Every 2 days' },
    { value: '3', label: 'Every 3 days' },
    { value: '4', label: 'Every 4 days' },
    { value: '5', label: 'Every 5 days' },
    { value: '6', label: 'Every 6 days' },
    { value: '7', label: 'Every 7 days' }
];

const defaultFormData = {
        dashboardCleanupDays: '7',
    }
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(defaultFormData);

const onChangeForm = (keyName, keyValue) => {
    let temp_value = keyValue
    if(keyName === 'domainName'){
        setDomainEdited(true);
        temp_value = temp_value.trim();
    }
    setFormData({
        ...formData,
        ...{ [keyName]: temp_value }
    });
}

<Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={2} className='pd0 txt-left'>
      <Select className="selectbox1"
      variant='outlined'
      MenuProps={{
          anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'left'
          },
          getContentAnchorEl: null,
          transitionDuration: 0
      }}
      onChange={(e) => onChangeForm('dashboardCleanupDays', e.target.value)}
      value={formData.dashboardCleanupDays}>
          {CLEAN_UP_DASHBOARD.map((dashItem) => {
              return <MenuItem value={dashItem.value}>{dashItem.label}</MenuItem>
          })}
      </Select>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, in my case the default value and label are shown correctly as expected. I would assume some other function makes use of `setFormData` that overwrites it.

Comment: Yup, your code works just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-dan-3v6j0w?file=/src/App.js . Create a useEffect with a dependency of formData that logs the form data to the console every time there's a change. That should give you an indication of whether or not something else is overwriting the formData state